# JsTree, place limits on search depth

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I want to restrict search results to only nodes in a particular folder. Is there a way to specify a search depth? If this is not possible how can I filter the search results?

Answer (score 1):

To filter the tree with only search matches, use the built-in search option show_only_matches:

```
    $("#MyTree").jstree({ 
        "search" : {  "case_insensitive" : true,
            "show_only_matches" : true
        },
    "plugins" : [ "html_data", "ui", "themeroller","search" ]
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example usage :

```
jQuery("#jsTree").bind("loaded.jstree", function(event, data) { }).jstree({
    "core": {},
    "json_data": {
        // Ajax request to load data
    },
    "themes": {
        "theme": "classic",
        "dots": true,
        "icons": true
    },
    "types": {
        "types": {
            "max_children": -2,
            "max_depth": -2
        }
    }
});
```

You can use max_depth & max_children params to limit the tree

Comment: The Types and Search plugins of JsTree are unrelated. There is no relationship between specifying a "max_depth" for types and the depth of a search.